# Безопасность при загрузке фото

Tags: php, безопасность

```
<?php
if (!$auth->authorize(auth::getCurrentUserId(), auth::getAccessToken())) die;

if (!empty($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'])) {

    require_once '../libs/AcImage.php';

    if (!getimagesize($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'])) {
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error','msg' => 'Выбранный файл не является изображением')); die;
    }

    if ($_FILES['photo']['size'] > 1024 * 1024 * 2) {
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error','msg' => 'Размер изображения превышает 2 мб.')); die;
    }

    $img = AcImage::createImage($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);
    $img->cropCenter('2pr', '2pr');
    AcImage::setRewrite(true);
    $img->save($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);

}
?>
```

Что я не учёл для соблюдения безопасности при загрузки файла на сервер?

Также: почему-то второе условие не работает при загрузке файла более 2 мб?

Comment: `2*pow(1024, 2)` попробуйте, хотя не в этом ошибка.. а что в `$_FILES['photo']['size']` лежит?

Comment: Так же необходимо прочитать про уязвимость загрузки картинок, когда в них встраивали код php и при выводе изображения выполнялся код и мог навредить приложению, это так же стоит учитывать не менее чем эту безопасную загрузку.

Comment: @MoloF, что?? Где вы такое нашли? Изображение не может быть интерпретатором PHP.

Comment: @ДенисНебесный может при криво настроенном сервере, я лично такое делал

Comment: @andreymal , как этого можно избежать? Можно ссылочку на подобный ресурс где этого можно избежать, видел как у друга случилось подобное и его сайт был слит, как обезопасить себя от этого?

Comment: @MoloF настраивать сервер правильно, чтобы каталог с изображениями не был каталогом, в котором разрешено выполнение скриптов

Comment: @andreymal , то есть исполнение происходит только в каталоге но не когда вызывается это изображение из него? Чтобы избежать этой проблемы достаточно просто правильно настроить сервер и директорию для хранения картинки?